# Pythonic way to create array with entries unique for row and column

Tags: python, random, python-2.x

I have a number of samples and want to pick a random subset of those of a defined length and repeat this process until every samples occurs 3 times, no sample occurring twice in a given row.

For example:

```
samples=range(12)
l=6
repeats=3
```

I expect 6 rows of 6 samples.
I would like to have something like:

```
[1, 2, 11, 7, 0, 3]
[2, 5, 0, 7, 10, 3]
[11, 0, 8, 7, 6, 1]
[4, 11, 5, 9, 3, 6]
[4, 9, 8, 1, 10, 2]
[9, 5, 6, 4, 8, 10]
```

I tried the following but it only worked in one case (by chance) when the samples were picked equally, I usually get

```
ValueError: sample larger than population
```

Code:

```
import random
samples=range(12)
measured={key:0 for key in samples}
while len(samples)>0:
    sample=random.sample(samples,6)
    print sample
    for s in sample:
        measured[s]+=1
        if measured[s]==3:
            samples.remove(s)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to tweek `numpy.random.choice` or from `itertools.permutations` but those didn't work because of the constrains above.

Is there a sample way I am overlooking or do I need to work with nested loops/ifs?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and show us a sample of your desired output?

Comment: I can dig out the working example later

Comment: Let me know if I understand correctly: You want a list of lists, where the inner lists (rows) are of length `l` and are drawn from `samples` randomly without replacement and each value from `samples` occurs in exactly 2 rows? That's not what the title indicates you are looking for, so please try to clear it up. Maybe break it down into a smaller example.

Comment: By "every samples occurs 3 times" do you mean _exactly_ three times or at least that many?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a math.random() function within python. I may be thinking of a different package. Hold on.

Comment: It also almost like you are looking to create three subsets? I see that you are already using numpy. Still, will popping the random element selected help?

Comment: @martineau I want every element to occur exactly three times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but based on your title you actually want a grid of numbers from `samples` satisfying the following conditions:

1. The entries are unique for every row and column
2. Each element in `samples` is repeated at most `repeats` times

I don't think there is an easy way to do this because each element in the grid depends on the other items in the grid.

One potential solution is to populate your grid one element at a time, snaking from the first element (top left) to the last (bottom right). At each location, you randomly pick out of a set of "valid" values, which would be the values that haven't already been chosen for that row or column and those that have not been chosen `repeats` times already.

However, this method is not guaranteed to find a solution every time. You can define a function to search for an arrangement until one is found.

Here is one implementation that I came up with using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

samples=range(12)
l=6
repeats=3

def try_make_grid(samples, l, repeats, max_tries=10):
    try_number = 0
    while(try_number < max_tries):
        try:
            # initialize lxl grid to nan
            grid = np.zeros((l, l))*np.nan

            counts = {s: 0 for s in samples}  # counts of each sample
            count_exhausted = set()           # which samples have been exhausted
            for i in range(l):
                for j in range(l):
                    # can't use values that already happened in this row or column
                    invalid_values = set(np.concatenate([grid[:,j], grid[i,:]]))
                    valid_values = [
                        v for v in samples if v not in invalid_values|count_exhausted
                    ]
                    this_choice = np.random.choice(a=valid_values)
                    grid[i,j] = this_choice

                    # update the count and check to see if this_choice is now exhausted
                    counts[this_choice] += 1
                    if counts[this_choice] >= repeats:
                        count_exhausted.add(this_choice)
            print("Successful on try number %d" % try_number)
            return grid
        except:
            try_number += 1
    print("Unsuccessful")
```

An example grid:

```
np.random.seed(42)
grid = try_make_grid(samples, l, repeats)
#Successful on try number 6
print(grid)
#[[10.  5.  8. 11.  3.  0.]
# [ 0. 11.  4.  8.  2.  5.]
# [ 1.  6.  0.  2.  7.  3.]
# [ 3.  2.  7. 10. 11.  9.]
# [ 4.  1.  9.  6.  8.  7.]
# [ 6.  9. 10.  5.  1.  4.]]
```

As you can see, each row and column is unique and each value was selected no more than `repeats` times (in this case, they are all selected exactly `repeats` times).

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(grid.ravel()))
#Counter({10.0: 3,
#         5.0: 3,
#         8.0: 3,
#         11.0: 3,
#         3.0: 3,
#         0.0: 3,
#         4.0: 3,
#         2.0: 3,
#         1.0: 3,
#         6.0: 3,
#         7.0: 3,
#         9.0: 3})
```

Comment: thanks! I wanted the repeats to occur exactly the number of times, but given the dimensions of the array, this should happen here everytime

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have clarified what you wanted, here's a revision of my original answer, which is a pure-python implementation based on the constraints. Changing the original answer was fairly easy, so I also added code to limit the number of iterations and print a little report at the end verifying it meets all the criteria.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
from pprint import pprint
import random


def pick_subset(population, length, repeat, max_iterations=1000000):
    iterations = 0

    while iterations < max_iterations:
        # Get subset where every sample value occurrs at exactly "repeat" times.
        while iterations < max_iterations:
            iterations += 1
            subset = [random.sample(population, length) for i in range(length)]
            measure = Counter(chain.from_iterable(subset))
            if all((iterations == repeat for iterations in measure.values())):
                break

        # Check whether there are no more than 2 repeats in per row.
        if all((all((iterations < 2 for iterations in Counter(row).values()))
                   for row in subset)):
            break

    if iterations >= max_iterations:
        raise RuntimeError("Couldn't match criteria after {:,d}".format(iterations))
    else:
        print('Succeeded after {:,d} iterations'.format(iterations))
        return subset


samples = range(12)
length = 6
repeat = 3

subset = pick_subset(samples, length, repeat)

print('')
print('Selected subset:')
pprint(subset)

# Show that each sample occurs exactly three times.
freq_counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(subset))
print('')
print('Overall sample frequency counts:')
print(', '.join(
        '{:2d}: {:d}'.format(sample, cnt) for sample, cnt in freq_counts.items()))


# Show that no sample occurs more than twice in a each row.
print('')
print('Sample frequency counts per row:')
for i, row in enumerate(subset):
    freq_counts = Counter(row)
    print('  row[{}]: {}'.format(i, ', '.join(
            '{:2d}: {:d}'.format(sample, cnt) for sample, cnt in freq_counts.items())))
```

Example output:

```
Succeeded after 123,847 iterations

Selected subset:
[[4, 9, 10, 2, 5, 7],
 [5, 8, 6, 0, 11, 1],
 [1, 8, 3, 10, 7, 0],
 [7, 3, 2, 4, 11, 9],
 [0, 10, 11, 6, 1, 2],
 [8, 3, 9, 4, 6, 5]]

Overall sample frequency counts:
 0: 3,  1: 3,  2: 3,  3: 3,  4: 3,  5: 3,  6: 3,  7: 3,  8: 3,  9: 3, 10: 3, 11: 3

Sample frequency counts per row:
  row[0]:  2: 1,  4: 1,  5: 1,  7: 1,  9: 1, 10: 1
  row[1]:  0: 1,  1: 1,  5: 1,  6: 1,  8: 1, 11: 1
  row[2]:  0: 1,  1: 1,  3: 1,  7: 1,  8: 1, 10: 1
  row[3]:  2: 1,  3: 1,  4: 1,  7: 1,  9: 1, 11: 1
  row[4]:  0: 1,  1: 1,  2: 1,  6: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1
  row[5]:  3: 1,  4: 1,  5: 1,  6: 1,  8: 1,  9: 1
```